# How to reload application.properties in runtime which is not part of jar

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, javabeans, properties-file

I have a problem with application.properties file which is not part of my war file. I want to create an application in which I will be able to change application.properties values in runtime. My properties file will be bean which we will be using in service.

**Classes of PoC below:**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class ServiceReaderConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    ServiceOutputProperties serviceProperties() {
        log.info("create serviceProperties");
        return new ServiceOutputProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceOutput serviceOutput() {
        log.info("create serviceOutput");
        return new ServiceOutput(serviceProperties());
    }
}
```

**ServiceProperty**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
@Setter
@Getter
public class ServiceOutputProperties {
    private int param;
}
```

**ServiceOutputProperties**

```
@Slf4j
public class ServiceOutput {

    private ServiceOutputProperties serviceOutputProperties;

    public ServiceOutput(ServiceOutputProperties serviceOutputProperties) {
        log.info("creating serviceOutputProperties");
        this.serviceOutputProperties = serviceOutputProperties;
    }

    public int printValueFromFile() {
        int param = serviceOutputProperties.getParam();
        return param;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ControllerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceOutput serviceOutput;

    @GetMapping("/print")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> postValueFromPropertiesFile() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(serviceOutput.printValueFromFile());
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
prefix.param=2
```

**XML file puted in Catalina file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Environment name="spring.config.location"
value="file:/home/marcin/tomcat/application.properties"
type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

I am building war package without application property file which i want to modify while runtime. Package is deploying on tomcat. All I want to achieve is to modify the properties file and display the changed value from the file using the controller in the runtime without the need to reload the application.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sounds like a reason to start to use spring cloud config. https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: @Gimby you right, i noticed that possibility but i am trying to find lighter solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive it using refresh scope feature from spring cloud, consider case:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
@PropertySource("path to properties file, you can inject it as property ${spring.config.location}")
@RefreshScope
public class ServiceOutputProperties {
  private int param;

//getters & setters
}
```

Later you can refresh beans like this in two ways: by sending POST request to endpoint `/actuator/refresh` (if you are using spring-actuator) or by injecting `RefreshScope` bean and calling `refreshAll()` method (or `refresh(String name)` if you want refresh single bean).

You can use [WatchService API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to create listener which will call one of above method on each file modification.

Refresh scope feature is included into [spring-cloud-context](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context) so I belive it's ligth enough